# How do i create an email contact form for my website

Tags: php, email, forms, sendmail, contacts

I'm looking to create a form on my website where users can enter their email address and a message (however long). Then upon clicking on a submit button, the code, sends the message as an email to my mailbox.

I was wondering if someone knew what code i could use. I am using PHP as my server-side language.

Comment: What serverside code does your hosting support? PHP? ASP? Only CGI?

Comment: So what do you want to know? Specifically?

Comment: I always forget to check the tags! Daft me. Oh well there are no stupid questions, just stupid people.

Comment: thanks.. i've made myself more specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have access to an smtp server somewhere. Assuming you do, use the php mail function to send the mail like so:

```
$Name = "John doe"; //senders name 
$email = "email@adress.com"; //senders e-mail adress 
$recipient = "recipient@emailadress.com"; //recipient 
$mail_body = "The text for the mail..."; //mail body 
$subject = "Subject for receiver"; //subject 
$header = "From: ". $Name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n"; //optional headerfields

mail($recipient, $subject, $mail_body, $header);
```

The smtp server is set in the php.ini file in these two lines:

```
SMTP = servername
smtp_port = 25
```

More information at [w3schools site](http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_mail.asp).

Answer (score 2):

while the above two answers provide a basic email sending suggestion, there's one thing you should consider, the codes are not secure. spammers can inject Cc: codes and send spam using the form. if they do, your smtp provider may ban your account. try a dedicated mailer, like [phpmailer](http://phpmailer.codeworxtech.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use **PHPForms**. It is an ultimate web [form builder](http://phpforms.net/tutorial/html-basics/form-builder.html) that allows to create professionally looking email forms  within just a few minutes. You will only need to create a PHP form by means of an intuitive interface and generate a code that can be easily copied and pasted to any web page.